# Access variable attached to template in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm reading through https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates, trying to pass a variable to a template. I've come up with:

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RowPopup');
html.row = sendableRow;
var h =html.evaluate();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(h, 'Create Documents');
```

which produces a popup as expected without error. In the template itself I have some JS/jquery functions like the following which I want to be able to interact with the passed in data:

```
   function buildOptionList(options) {
        var list = $('#optionList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            console.log(options[i]);
            list.append('<option value="' + options[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
        }
```

But I can't find how to access the variable "row" that I have attached to the template from within the page. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `.evaluate()` Google creates a HTML document from the file and variables you have given. It knows which sections to evaluate by using [printing scriptlets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#printing_scriptlets) such as `<?= row ?>`. This evaluation is done before being sent to the client to display. You [should just be able to](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates#pushing_variables_to_templates) access it with `row` as seen in the linked code example.

```
var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('RowPopup');
html.row = sendableRow;
var h =html.evaluate();
SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
    .showModalDialog(h, 'Create Documents');

//In the HTML file.
  <body>
    <?= row ?>
  </body>
```

You may instead be interested in [client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) to get the data after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, that gets me part of the way there but How can I assign the object to a variable (lets say var options), so that I can work on it with js in the template as in the function above

Comment: @user61629 Honestly, in that case, I would make a call back to the script using the client-server-communication thing I posted. But if you wanted to stick with you current method something like `var myData = '<?= data ?>';`  in the <script> tags should do it with a little fooling around.

Comment: thanks, I ended up passing it in as json then converting it back to an object all within the script tags.